# Giving the_excerpt in the place of the_content?

Tags: hooks, excerpt, the-content

Short and sweet — I wanted to deliver up the excerpt of a post in the place of `the_content` on certain pages. Naturally, if no excerpt is present one would be generated from the content. I understand I can just go in and edit the theme files, but I'd like a less-invasive method.

Seeing how something like the following works:

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc ( $content ) {
  the_title();
}
```

I thought I would try this

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc ( $content ) {
  the_excerpt();
}
```

This. Fails. Gloriously. It results in a fatal error, actually:

> FATAL ERROR: MAXIMUM FUNCTION NESTING LEVEL OF '100' REACHED, ABORTING! IN C:\WAMP\WWW\WORDPRESS\WP-INCLUDES\POST.PHP ON LINE 555

This is followed by a massive call stack, which appears to have been set into a mad frenzy of recursive calls.

**Turning the Tables**

So this got me curious, and I tried the opposite. Deliver `the_content` in the place of `the_excerpt`:

```
add_action( 'the_excerpt', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc ( $content ) {
  the_content();
}
```

This, to my surprise, worked just fine. So what I'm gathering is that `the_excerpt` calls `the_content`, but `the_content` doesn't call `the_excerpt` - this would certainly explain the fact that it works one way, but the other seems to be set off in a massive fit of recursion.

Not being very familiar with the inner-workings of these two function, I was curious what the community here could provide in way of insight. What's the problem with hooking into `the_content` and calling `the_excerpt`?

How can I achieve this effect if not by calling `the_content` directly? I understand that I could provide my own custom excerpt logic, but this would de-normalize the excerpt logic in my site, meaning I'd have some excerpts being created via custom code in the functions.php, and others created via the internal methods of WordPress - ideally, I would avoid this and use only the internal methods if possible.

Answer (score 2):

All good examples. But they weren't working for me with the theme (pinboard) and plugin I was using (secondary-html-content) and what I wanted to do.

The first challenge was to make sure that I get both pieces of content instead of just one. The second challenge was to replace the excerpt on the homepage with the actual content.

So I created a new plugin that does this:

```
function okmAddingContentExcerpt() {
    global $post;
    $content = '<div class="comment-first">'.$post->post_content.'</div>';
    // Adia Review is the name of the label from secondary-html-content plugin
    $content .= '<div class="comment-second">'.get_secondary_content('Adia Review',$post->ID).'</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'okmAddingContentExcerpt');

function okmAddingContentSingle() {
    global $post;
    $content = '<div class="comment-first">'.$post->post_content.'</div>';
    // remove the filter so that it doesn't loop over and over
    remove_filter('the_content','okmAddingContentSingle');
    $content .= '<div class="comment-second">'.get_secondary_content('Adia Review',$post->ID).'</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'okmAddingContentSingle');
```

Notice how I wanted to keep the content instead of the excerpt on the main page.

Oh yeah, if you want to download the plugin, I added it to my blog-site: http://okmaya.com/wordpress-plugin-for-pinboard-theme-and-secondary-html-content-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `the_excerpt()` calls `get_the_excerpt()`, which outputs `$post->post_excerpt`.

One thing, also: shouldn't you be using `add_filter()` instead of `add_action()`?

Why are you using `the_excerpt()`/`the_content()`/`the_title()`, rather than setting `$content` = `get_the_excerpt()` etc., and then returning `$content`? e.g. this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc ( $content ) {
  the_excerpt();
}
```

...would normally be written as such:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc ( $content ) {
  $content = get_the_excerpt();
  return $content;
}
```

Not sure if any of that will address your problem of the recursive loop...

**EDIT**

Your last comment gave me an idea: why not just pass $content through `wp_trim_excerpt()` and be done with it?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc( $content ) {
    $excerpt = wp_trim_excerpt( $content );
    return $excerpt;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Okay, I'm with you now. How about we roll our own excerpt function?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'myFunc' );
function myFunc( $content ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $content );
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
         array_pop($words);
         $text = implode(' ', $words);
         $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
     } else {
         $text = implode(' ', $words);
     }        
     return $text;
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean `the_excerpt` calls `the_content` directly, sorry for the confusion. `the_excerpt` calls `wp_trim_excerpt` which itself calls `get_the_content`. I'm not sure where things are going crazy, to be honest. The other suggestions in your answer didn't help, unfortunately. Whether I use `add_action` or `add_filter`, it made no difference in this case. I also moved to returning the values as opposed to implicitly outputting them with the `the_` functions - still no improvement.

Comment: I just realized I forgot one important bit of information. There are no excerpts - the excerpts ought to be generated from the content. So something like `global $post; return $post->post_excerpt;` would work, but would be empty.

Comment: Hmm... okay, see updated answer for a different idea.

Comment: I've tried that as well, actually. Oddly enough it only returns a formatted content - no limit in chars as expected.

Comment: `wp_trim_excerpt()` calls `$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);` which is the cause of the recursive calls. maybe try to extract the code from `wp_trim_excerpt()` from /wp-includes/formatting.php line 1830, leaving the above line away - although i have no idea how essential this line is for the excerpts.

Comment: Okay, see Edit #2; let's try rolling our own excerpt trim function.

Comment: @Chip I could definitely write my own logic, however then I start to fracture my excerpt logic throughout the site. That is, unless I provide a global re-write for all excerpts, and not only those provided in the place of `the_content`.